# "tns doctor" "You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system." but everything is installed

Tags: android, nativescript

I have installed Android Studio and further installed the SDKs and tools via Android Studio. Here they are:

[image]
[image]

And my `$ANDROID_HOME` paths to the following: /Users/USER/Library/Android/sdk both in the terminal as well as in Android Studio.

However, when running tns doctor I get the following:

> (...)  Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient
>   ◟ Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient  ◜
>   Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient  ◠
>   Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient  ◝
>   Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient  ◞
>   Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient  ◡
>   Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient..
>
> You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system.
>   You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=25'. Run $
>   $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager from your command-line to install
>   required Android Build Tools.

Running "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager" simply echoes a "help" prompt.

What exactly is happening here and how can I fix this so I can run "npm run android" and android related operations?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Open CMD and do: `echo %ANDROID_HOME%`. If it echoes that exact text you haven't set the `ANDROID_HOME` environmental variable. Adding the SDK root to `PATH` should do though

Comment: @zoe I forgot to mention I am using OS X. And as I said in the question `$ANDROID_HOME paths to the following: /Users//Library/Android/sdk` so doing `echo $ANDROID_HOME` echoes that same path. I really don't understand why this should be happening.

Any other idea?

Comment: Not familiar with os x but there's a `//` in there. If that isn't a typo here or supported by os x, remove one of them

Comment: @Zoe that's a typo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved by executing `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.2"`

Comment: if you don't know the build-tools versions you have, you can do `ls $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools` (if you have your android home env var setup correctly, that is)

Comment: Also, according to nativescript docs, you need 27.0.3 or later https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me, needing the version 33 was:

1. Add this to your ~/.zshrc  or similar

   export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
2. Download the 33.0.2 from [here](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools).
3. On your $HOME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools delete the 34.0.0, and copy the downloaded one, but rename its folder from android-13 to 33.0.2
4. On Android Studio SDK Manager>SDK Tools> Download the Android SDK CLI
5. On your terminal run `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.2"`
6. `ns doctor android` should be fine now. Enjoy !

Comment: I was in the same boat (wanting to use v33) and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I installed Android Studio and dependencies before installing nativescript. What solved the issue for me was:

1. uninstall/reinstall Android Studio
2. Set Android_Home and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to the location of the sdk that android studio
   is pointed too.
3. restart terminal run tns doctor again.